# In C# MSMQ ,How to check Receiving application had received messages from Queue messages or not

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I am having C# application where I am using MSMQ to send/receive message from one application to another. In this application I had created private non transactional queue. On live environment, in one day more then 5000+ message process through this application. Sometime might be due to overload, when application sent message to queue, that message was not get received by Receiving application & it get stuck in Queue message. So is there any way by which we can check or identify that Receiving application had received messages from Queue messages or not.

Comment: The receiving end should send an ACK with an ID when each message is received (or a response when  message was processed).

Comment: @jdweng Is there any link for code reference ?

Comment: No.  It is standard Communication Protocol for reliable systems with queues.  There should be no reason a message get stuck in the queue and you should find out why.  Most likely you code that removes an item has issues.